# How do I copy bones from one armature to another?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have 2 armatures. I want to copy one subset of bones from the first armature to the second -- in Edit Mode -- in order to have the same bones, same names, same transforms on the second armature.

What I have tried:

A) in Edit Mode, Ctrl+C the bones from the first armature, CTRL+V to the second armature also in Edit Mode. This doesn't work because Copy/Paste will actually copy the entire Armature Object in Object Mode, and will paste a new object with all the bones.

B) in Edit Mode, Shift+D to duplicate the bones in the first armature, then try to unparent them from the first armature and parent them to the second. But I couldn't figure how to unparent the bones from the armature, all the unparenting options I could find would only unparent the bones from their current parent bone, but they'd stay inside the first armature.

Is there any way to do this in Blender or am I going to have to manually rebuild all the bones, one by one, on the second armature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were correct with your unparenting strategy. The shortcut to seperate a Bone is <kbd>P</kbd>. Then select your separate armature and <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the armature where you want the object to be and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: That worked, thanks! Only difference was that the hotkey to Separate bones was only "P", not "Ctrl+Alt+P". Other than that your solution worked perfectly.

Comment: btw, Ctrl+J is to join the two armatures. Blender is so intuitive but my intuition failed this time, so thx! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to have the whole process written out end-to-end:

1. Select the bones you want copied in Edit mode on the source armature. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate them. (Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> immediately will avoid accidentally moving them if you find that undesirable.)
2. With just the duplicate bones selected (should happen automatically after duplication), <kbd>P</kbd> to separate the selected bones into an entirely new armature object.
3. Exit edit mode. Select the newly formed armature, then the destination armature. Join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Note that the bones will probably still have `.001` at the end of their names. You can rename them as soon as you've separated them into the intermediate armature if you like.